# ActiveRecord query by pairs of values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 5.1+, and I'd like to query a model based on two conditions, which can have multiple values but always two by two.

Let's say I a have a `User` model, which has a `first_name` and `last_name`.
I'm looking for users having exactly either:

```
first_name: "John"
last_name: "Doe"
```

or

```
first_name: "Jane"
last_name: "Snow"
```

How can I write a query specifying this? 
I can always generate a SQL query string that I'd pass to a `where` clause but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What database are you using? If it's postegresql there's a particular SQL expression that's significantly more performent than other approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to define a helper method in your model and use `or` method  (*not tested*):

```
class User
  def self.where_in_pairs(values = [])
    values.map { |(first_name, last_name)| 
      where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name) 
    }.reduce(:or)
  end
end
```

And call like this:

```
User.where_in_pairs([["John", "Doe"], ["Jane", "Snow"]])
```

You can also use plain arel for that (*tested*):

```
class User
  def self.where_in_pairs(values = [])
    where(
      values.map { |(first_name, last_name)| 
        arel_table[:first_name].eq(first_name).and(
          arel_table[:last_name].eq(last_name)
        ) 
      }.reduce(:or)
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what's the most efficient query of these 2 from your opinion ? If we consider a large number of couples

Comment: @GrahamSlick: you are welcome, these two queries generate the same sql, so it doesn't matter really, it is just that  the first example is only Rails 5+ compatible

Comment: @GrahamSlick: you might undergo issues with parenthesis if you want to query with 10000+ values, so I would suggest using `.reduce{|s, x| Arel::Nodes::Or.new(s, x)}` instead of `.reduce(:or)` in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) IN ("John Doe", "Jane Snow")
```

In rails

```
first_name_last_names = ["John Doe", "Jane Snow"]
USER.where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) IN (?)", first_name_last_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ransack (`gem install ransack`) and calling something like:

`User.ransack(first_name_and_last_name_cont: “John Smith”)`

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/README.md (Note you don’t have to have a search form to utilize ransack)

Another option is to write two scopes, one for first name and one for last name and chain them.

```
class User
  scope :by_first_name, -> (first_name) { where(first_name: first_name) }
  scope :by_last_name, -> (last_name) { where(last_name: last_name) }
end
```

`User.by_first_name(“John”).by_last_name(“Smith”)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know Ransack, and I've used it, but if the number of conditions is high, it just fails to return anything

Comment: The number of conditions being the number of attributes, i.e., more than just first name and last name? What about using scopes?

Comment: No I meant the number of possible combinations e.g more than just John Doe or Jane Snow (think 1000+ possibilities)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails OR operator, but it is a recursive call so I don't know if there is something better than this :

```
first_name, last_name = names.pop
users = User.where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)

while ((first_name, last_name) = names.pop) do
   users = User.where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name).or(users)
end

#your result is in 'users'
```

An other solution would be to add a `name` column, and use a before_save callback, with `self.name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"` in order to use `User.where(name:[])`

A third solution (but it makes 1 SQL request per name) :

```
User.where(id: names.each { |first_name, last_name| User.where(first_name: f, last_name, l).pluck(:id) })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that adding a column just for this use is overkill